# Flutter Alignment

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am very new to flutter development. Currently learning Row, Column, Expanded UI stuffs. I want the row to be in this fashion [Image of Row I need to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJ8dP.png) and this is what I am getting currently [Output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjS3v.jpg), this is my code :`

```
Widget drawerTiles(String tileIcon, String tileText, IconData tileRightIcon) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 16, right: 32.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          CircleAvatar(
            radius: 14,
            backgroundColor: Hexcolor('#0565ac'),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              child: SvgPicture.asset(
                tileIcon,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            tileText,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.black),
          ),
          Icon(tileRightIcon)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

`

It is a custom widget as you can see and I am passing the necessary parameters for it. The issue is with alignment probably. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve that easily using ListTile widget

[ListTile widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html)

Comment: Indeed, I just found out. Thanks for this @Ridha Rezzag 